# Issue with opening collapsible sections

Tags: html, css

I am working with an HTML page in which I have put 8 collapsible sections made purely of CSS (I want to avoid the use of scripts where possible and plausible).

The issue that I am experiencing is that when I click one collapsible section (to open it), all of the following collapsible sections open as well, and I cannot close them unless I first close the initial one that I first opened. For instance, if I open collapsible #3, then collapsibles #4, #5, #6, #7, #8 open too, and none can be closed until I close collapsible #3.

Below is my code.
CSS:

```
    margin: 10% auto;
    width: 700px;
    z-index: -5;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

label.first {
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 25px 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
        border-radius: 7px;
        box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    width: 70vw;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    
}

label.first:hover {
    background: #26C281;
}

ul ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #59ABE3;
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] ~ ul {
    height: 0;
    display: none;
    transform: scaleY(0);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
    transform: scaleY(1); 
    display: flex;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background: #26C281;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

HTML (the last section):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="list-item-8">
    <label for="list-item-8" class="first"><span class="badge badge-secondary">8.</span> Review your Data &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    <span id="collapseButtton" class="iconify" data-icon="fa-solid:chevron-circle-down" data-inline="false"></span></label>


<ul>
<div id="review" class="wrapper container-fluid">

    <h5 class="stath5"><span class="badge badge-secondary">8.</span> Review</h5>
    <h6 class="stath6"><em>Kindly take the time to check your data for errors before submiting.</em></h6>
    

</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the general sibling selector (~), that is going to select more than you want. You should be using the next sibling selector. (+)

```css
.section-toggle,
.section-toggle + label + ul {
  display: none;
}

.section-toggle + label,
.section-toggle:checked + label + ul {
  display: block;
}

.section-toggle:checked + ul {
  background-color: #cCF;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="section-toggle">
<label for="cb1">Test 1</label>
<ul>
  <li>Test content 1</li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" class="section-toggle">
<label for="cb2">Test 2</label>
<ul>
  <li>Test content 2</li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" class="section-toggle">
<label for="cb3">Test 3</label>
<ul>
  <li>Test content 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like it'll work, I'll accept it after I've confirmed thus

Comment: Ok man, that is not the issue apparently. I tried to do so, now all the sections are open by default and I can't close any

Comment: Well I used different markup... I altered it to be a ul instead of a div

Comment: That isn't different from mine. I also am using a <ul> to wrap the content I want to be shown

Comment: Thank you for your trouble, sir, finally I have resolved said issue. Thanks and God bless you.